# black ops 2 zombies camera movement problem

Tags: call-of-duty-black-ops-2

I play *Call of Duty: Black Ops 2* on my PS3, and there's a weird thing going on with the camera which **only** seems to happen in **Zombies Mode**. (*I **never** run into this problem in multiplayer*)

Sometimes, when I want to turn my view to left or right (to look left or right), the movement of the camera isn't smooth and continuous as it's in the multiplayer mode, it does something weird. It's like it starts normal, then does like a "pause" (almost stopping) and then continues normal. *This occurs whilst holding the right stick in the same position all the time*, not that I'm doing anything weird with it.

Sometimes it happens when the terrain I'm on it's not totally flat, but I think it happens in other situations as well. Any ideas of why this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Zombies mode is technically a 'cooperative campaign' mode (rather than a 'multiplayer' game), the same auto-aim assist which exists in the single-player campaign carries over into zombie games.

So what is happening is that you're turning in circles, and as your crosshair passes over a zombie it slows down your turning. It helps if you wanted to aim/shoot at that zombie, but in other scenarios (quick turning to run from/melee a closer zombie for example) it can be quite annoying.

<s>You can disable aim assist in the settings. I don't own Black Ops 2, but if memory serves from earlier games it is under the `Look Sensitivity` sub-menu and is called `Target Assist`.</s>

It appears *Black Ops 2*'s Zombie mode has it's own aim assistance, separate to the option you can toggle in the settings menu ([Source](http://www.xim3.com/community/index.php?topic=24551.0)). Which can't be completely disabled.

This may be a bug on Treyarch's end, or by design. You could try contacting them with the relevant details, to see if this is the case.

Comment: thanks for your reply! It turns out you nailed the reason but not the solution. I just tested it and yes, it seems to do that when you're turning and the cross-hair points to a zombie. However, the weird thing is that I have auto-aim already turned off! If I turn it on, it does the same thing, and in addition the aiming gets super annoying since it "snaps" the cross-hair to the targets (zombies) a lot, which is why I had it turned off...

Comment: @Albert - I've done some more digging, it appears that this aim assistance is different from the 'Target Assist' I mentioned earlier. see my edits